# Contra/covariance issues with generics

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I am try to create types of particular classes but I can't return them back out as their generic representation, can someone please tell me how to achieve that?  I am a bit light on contra/covariance magic

```
public DashboardNotification<IDashboardEntry> Get()
{
    //return new MyNotWorkingNotification(); // doesn't compile, I want to achieve this
    return new MyWorkingNotification(); // compiles
}

public class DashboardNotification<T> where T : IDashboardEntry
{
}

public interface IDashboardEntry
{
}

public class MyNotWorkingNotification : DashboardNotification<MyDashboardEntry>
{
}

public class MyWorkingNotification : DashboardNotification<IDashboardEntry>
{
}

public class MyDashboardEntry : IDashboardEntry
{
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's rename your types.

```
interface IAnimal {}
class Cage<T> where T : IAnimal {}
class Tiger : IAnimal {}
```

Your question is: I have a `Cage<Tiger>` and I want it to be used as a `Cage<IAnimal>` because a tiger is an animal.

Now do you see why that is illegal? A cage of tigers can only hold tigers; a cage of animals can hold any animal. If a cage of tigers could be used as a cage of animals then you could put a fish into the tiger cage, which would make neither the tiger nor the fish very happy.

What you want is generic class covariance, but C# only supports generic covariance on interfaces and delegates.

Comment: Agreed on that, so I would need an interface as such *IDashboardNotification<out T> where T : IDashboardEntry*?  Is that the only solution?

Comment: @Ruskin: That is *a* solution, but far from the *only* solution. A preferred solution is: stop trying to capture so much in the generic type system. It's not designed to represent complex relationships.  It looks like you're trying to encode business logic in the type system; don't do that.

Comment: No business logic in the example above so not sure how you are inferring that?  Also, isn't that exactly what the covariance was introduced...to represent "complex" relationships?